# How to make navbar change color on scroll, but only when the screen width is greater than 600px?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have this function that will change the color of the navbar when scrollTop is greater than 100. Then I added an if statement that should only add the scroll event listener when the screen width is greater than 600px. The problem is that the code is not working.

```
const nav = document.querySelector('.navbar');

function addScrollStyle() {
  nav.style.backgroundColor = document.documentElement.scrollTop > 100 ? 'rgba(33,33,33,1)' : 'rgba(0,0,0,0)';
  nav.style.transition = 'all .2s ease-out';
}

if (window.innerWidth > '600') {
  nav.addEventListener('scroll', addScrollStyle);
}
```

I'm not really sure why it's not working. I've tried this in jQuery as well but I was doing the same thing. So I'm trying to stick to vanilla JS as of right now, because I understand it better. Anyways help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Will `window.innerWidth > '600'` work correctly when `'600'` is a string?

Comment: the second argument to `addEventListener`, I don't think it takes that kind of callback try nav.addEventListener('scroll', () => { addScrollStyle() });`

Comment: @BrandonBenefield - `addScrollStyle` is a function, which is exactly what the second argument should be

Comment: @perfect5th - it does, though I'd personally write the 600 as a NUMBER

Comment: `code is not working` - can you explain a bit more. Are there errors in the developer tools console for example? "code is not working" contains virtually no information to help you

Comment: no it won't work if it's a string or not

Comment: No there are no errors in the console

Comment: again, "won't work" means nothing. What is it you are observing? How have you tried to debug it? a few well placed `console.log` statements may help you determine what your code is doing

Comment: When using a either a string or not I can get it to add the event listener once, but then after that it will just stay there

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that your `window.innerWidth` check will only trigger once; on page load. You need to wrap this in a function that is called every time the window is resized, which can be done with `window.onresize`. Also, the `600` must be a **number**, not a string.

```js
const nav = document.querySelector('.navbar');

function addScrollStyle() {
  nav.style.backgroundColor = document.documentElement.scrollTop > 100 ? 'rgba(33,33,33,1)' : 'rgba(0,0,0,0)';
  nav.style.transition = 'all .2s ease-out';
}

window.onresize = function(event) {
  if (window.innerWidth > 600) {
    nav.addEventListener('scroll', addScrollStyle);
  }
};
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: why mix `addEventListener('event',` with `onevent` styles? seems odd :p

Comment: also, this will likely had many many scroll event listeners when resizing the window - eventually causing a meltdown

Comment: Yeah it still hasn't fixed the problem

Comment: `if (window.innerWidth > 600) {
      addEventListener('load', function(){
        addEventListener('scroll', function(){
          nav.style.backgroundColor = document.documentElement.scrollTop > 100 ? 'rgba(33,33,33,1)' : 'rgba(0,0,0,0)';
          nav.style.transition = 'all .2s ease-out';
        });
      });
    }`

Comment: So now i've got this and it will work, but it works whether the screen is less than or greater than 600px